# Calling a function from temp.py returns None

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

When searching on the Internet I've found a lot of helpful information, but nothing seems to be working. I'm trying call a function from `temp.py` and use it in `temp2.py`. However, I'm getting `None` when I print. How can I fix this?

Here is `temp.py`:

```
import Adafruit_DHT
import math
humidity, temperature= Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(Adafruit_DHT.DHT22, 4)

def temp():
    Celsius = int(temperature)
    Fah = 9.0/5.0 * Celsius + 32
    print Fah
    return temp
print temp()
```

Comment: `temp()` returns the function object itself here. `Fah` is not returned, it is only written to `stdout`.

Comment: You should be passing `temperature` in as a parameter like so: `def temp(temperature)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Martijn Pieters mentioned, your function returns itself here:

```
return temp
```

Instead, you should remove these lines:

```
print Fah
return temp
```

And replace them with:

```
return Fah
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the line that reads `return temp` should say `return Fah`